# Express Router doesn't route as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, neo4j, routes

Running NodeJS on Ubuntu 20.04.2, using VSApp with the debugger

I have the following file named /src/routes/regions.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const { int } = require('neo4j-driver')
const { required, optional } = require('../middleware/auth')
const { check } = require('express-validator')
const validate = require('../middleware/validate')
const neo4j = require('../neo4j')

const Joi = require('joi');

const Region = require('../entities/Region')

router.get('/1', (req, res, next) => {

    return req.neo4j.read(`
        MATCH (regions:Region) 
        return regions order by regions.name ASC
    `, params)
        .then(regions => res.send(regions))
        .catch(e => next(e))

})

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    return req.neo4j.read(`
        MATCH (regions:Region) 
        return regions order by regions.name DESC
    `, params)
        .then(regions => res.send(regions))
        .catch(e => next(e))

})

router.get('/:name', (req, res, next) => {

    const params = {
        name: req.params ? req.params.name : null
    }

    return req.neo4j.read(`
        MATCH (region:Region { name: $name }) return region 
    `, params)
    .then(regions => res.send(regions))
    .catch(e => next(e))

})

module.exports = router;
```

From a browser, if I enter `localhost:3000/regions` I receive the list of all the Regions in Descending order.

But if I try to enter `localhost:3000/regions/1` I receive nothing. The only difference between the two calls should be the order of the received data. The same for `localhost:3000/regions/Lazio`

It looks like it is not able to recognize patterns in the provided URL

The other really strange behavior is that if I set a breakpoint on any line of the file, the debugger doesn't stop. It looks like it is running another program ....

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first route needs to include the name parameter. Express routes aren't inclusive of any others defined elsewhere, so you need to spell it out a bit.

```
router.get('/:name/1', (req, res, next) => {
```

Comment: Correct, or even add a second param for the id 
/:name/:id
regions/1 => (name = regions, id = 1) 
regions/Lazio => (name = regions, id = Lazio)